# Postgresql: Sortable index on array values

Tags: postgresql, array

Suppose the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (id serial, category int, bar int[]);
INSERT INTO foo VALUES (1, 1, '{4,10,20}');
INSERT INTO foo VALUES (2, 1, '{1,8,9}');
```

We want to query sorted individual values from `bar` column. This can be achieved with this query:

```
SELECT unnest(bar) AS u, id FROM foo ORDER BY u;                                                                                                                 
 u  | id 
----+----
  1 |  2
  4 |  1
  8 |  2
  9 |  2
 10 |  1
 20 |  1
```

How we can build an index for this query?

UPDATE:

- Version of postgres is not important, lets say we want to implement with latest version (9.5)
- `bar` column is variable-length, different rows may have different number of elements, (but no empty array).
- Elements are not null.
- We want an index to support efficient queries with `LIMIT` (so not retrieving all rows in queries, see blow)
- This is a simplified version of an actual (in design) use-case.

UPDATE:
Example with `LIMIT` clause

```
SELECT unnest(bar) AS u, id FROM foo WHERE category = 1 ORDER BY u LIMIT 3;                                                                                                                 
 u  | id 
----+----
  1 |  2
  4 |  1
  8 |  2
```

Comment: Please always provide your version of Postgres. And is this your actual use case? All arrays of same length? And retrieve *all* rows? Can there be NULL elements? Empty arrays? NULL arrays? And do you want to include a row for each of these cases in the result?

Comment: Can you adapt your example to show how `LIMIT` will be applied? In combination with `WHERE` conditions or varying `ORDER BY`?

Answer (score 2):

If your use case is to retrieve *all* array elements of all rows, an index is not going to help with that. Postgres indexes can only hold a single index entry for a single table row. And a GIN index would not support the sort.

The best option I see would be a [`MATERIALIZED VIEW`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-creatematerializedview.html) - which needs a refresh after any write operations on the underlying table that might influence the result. So probably only useful for read-only (or mostly) tables.

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW foo_elements AS
SELECT unnest(bar) AS u, id
FROM   foo
ORDER  BY u;
```

Comment: Does using a GiST index with custom operator class help?

Comment: @TahaJahangir: I am tempted to say: "depends on the operator class", but I don't see how that could work at all. The default operator class certainly doesn't.

Comment: You say "Postgres indexes can only hold a single index entry for a single table row." Does this mean that it is impossible to have a separate index for each element?

Comment: @Vérace: Each index would have *one* index entry per table row, so there is no conflict with my statement.

Answer (score 1):

An answer to your query can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13353472/470530).

```
CREATE TABLE test (foo int[]);
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('{1,2,3}');
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('{4,5,6}');
CREATE INDEX test_index on test ((foo[1]));
```

Must be version >= 9.2.1. You have to create a separate index for each element. But as your friend Herr Brandstetter points out in a comment, it's not really of much use because if you

> "have a fixed number of array elements, you'd rather use individual
>   columns for each element (and plain btree indices) instead of building
>   a more expensive expression index for each array item. Storage of
>   individual columns is much cheaper without array overhead, too."

Comment: `bar` arrays are in variable lengths.